# JDBC BigDecimal with SQLite

Tags: sqlite, jdbc, bigdecimal

I am trying to recieve a Big Decimal from an SQL table containing DECIMAL(13,4) using the following code:

```
        userStmt = userConn.createStatement();
        userRsst = userStmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM WITHDRAWALS WHERE     date BETWEEN " 
                + "'" + limits[0] + "' " + "AND " + "'" + limits[1] + "'");
        try{
            while(userRsst.next()){
            if(Double.parseDouble(userRsst.getString("amount")) != 0){
            temp = userRsst.getBigDecimal("amount");
            }else{
                temp = new BigDecimal("0.0");
            }

                }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return(null);
    }
        finally{
            this.userDisconnect();
        }
    }catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not retrieve withdrawal data 2");
        return null;
    }   
    return wdb;
}
```

But I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: not implemented by SQLite JDBC driver
at org.sqlite.Unused.unused(Unused.java:29)
at org.sqlite.Unused.getBigDecimal(Unused.java:88)
at dat.handle.DBconnection.getWithdrawals(DBconnection.java:233)
at GUI.MainWindow.updateWithdrawalTree(MainWindow.java:372)
at GUI.MainWindow.open(MainWindow.java:217)
```

Can anyone point out what I have done wrong?

Thank you

Jonas

Comment: what exactly is your query? select * from withdrawals where WHAT??

Comment: SELECT * FROM WITHDRAWALS WHERE date BETWEEN '02/01/2011' AND '02/31/2011'. Seams to be working fine both in other queries and in the external terminal application. It seams like my JDBC driver v0.56 does not have the support for BigDecimals

Comment: I am adding more code later but I have removed most of it and backtracked the problem to this.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a work around for the time being by using get string and recasting the variable like this:

```
temp = new BigDecimal(userRsst.getString("amount"));
```

Still would be nice to understand why the "getBigDecimal" function throws an SQLException though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the fork of the JDBC Driver for SQLite provided by David Crawshaw

https://github.com/gwenn/sqlitejdbc

Adds:

- Adds basic support to BigDecimal, BinaryStream, CharacterStream, AsciiStream.
- Stores Dates and Times as julian day number.
- Introduces a cache to make ResultSet#findColumn(String) faster.

Regards,
Pedro Sousa

Answer (score 0):

setBigDecimal() didnt work for me as well. Replaced with String, it will be working.